# Power BI: Quarter over Quarter %Change

Tags: powerbi, dax

To start, here is the Power BI I am working with:

[image: Power BI Table]

I want to calculate the %Change in Cost Quarter over Quarter.

As shown in the table above, I have the Cost Total for Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 in the `Total Cost by Quarter Column`, which I calculated using this formula:

```
Total Cost By Quarter =
IF (
    [Quarters] = "Q1",
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( CR_Months_ByMonth[Cost] ),
        FILTER ( CR_Months_ByMonth, [Quarters] = "Q1" )
    ),
    IF (
        [Quarters] = "Q2",
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( CR_Months_ByMonth[Cost] ),
            FILTER ( CR_Months_ByMonth, [Quarters] = "Q2" )
        ),
        IF (
            [Quarters] = "Q3",
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( CR_Months_ByMonth[Cost] ),
                FILTER ( CR_Months_ByMonth, [Quarters] = "Q3" )
            ),
            IF (
                [Quarters] = "Q4",
                CALCULATE (
                    SUM ( CR_Months_ByMonth[Cost] ),
                    FILTER ( CR_Months_ByMonth, [Quarters] = "Q4" )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However, I could not figure out how to calculate %Change between quarters using another Calculated column, due to the repeating values (multiple Q1s, Q2s, etc in `[Total Cost By Quarter]`).

So, I attempted to calculate the %Change using Measures. 
I made a measure for the Q1 Cost, Q2 Cost, Q3 Cost, and Q4 Cost, using a formula like the one below:

```
Q1Sum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( CR_Months_ByMonth[Cost] ),
    FILTER ( CR_Months_ByMonth, [Quarters] = "Q1" )
)
```

I then made a new measure to calculate Q12%Change, Q23%Change, and Q34%Change, using a formula like the one below:

```
Q12%Change =
 ( DIVIDE ( [Q2Sum] - [Q1Sum], [Q1Sum] ) )
    * 100
```

This is the result that I get using the calculated measures:

[image: %Change Quarter over Quarter Attempt]

This structure does not yield good visuals and I am certain there is a simpler, more efficient way to accomplish Quarter over Quarter %Change.

This is my desired result:

[image: Correct Structure]

As a final note, I do have a date table that looks like this:

[image: Date Table]

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Total Cost by Quarter]` should be as simple as `SUM(CR[Cost])` if placed into a matrix that has quarters on the rows/columns.

The trickier part is referencing the previous quarter to get the percent change. It will look something like this:

```
% Change =
    VAR PrevQtrCost = CALCULATE(SUM(CR[Cost]), PREVIOUSQUARTER(DateTable[Date]))
    RETURN DIVIDE(SUM(CR[Cost]), PrevQtrCost) - 1
```

The `VAR` line might be a bit different depending on how exactly you have your `DateTable` related to the `CR` table.

---

Also take a look at this similar question: [Power BI: Percent Change Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791874/power-bi-percent-change-formula)

---

If you aren't linking on a date, then try something along these lines:

```
% Change =
    VAR PrevQtr = MOD(MAX(DateTable[FiscalQuarterNumber]) - 2, 4) + 1
    VAR PrevQtrCost = CALCULATE(SUM(CR[Cost]), DateTable[FiscalQuarterNumber] = PrevQtr)
    RETURN DIVIDE(SUM(CR[Cost]), PrevQtrCost) - 1
```

Comment: I tried using the above code for %Change, but am getting the following result: 
Q1: -1%
Q2: 3%
Q3: 3%
Q4: 2%, 

which is incorrect. I think this issue is occurring because I need "Quarter" to be defined as it is in the Fiscal Year (i.e Q1 = Oct-Dec, Q2 = Jan-Mar, Q3 = Apr-Jun, and Q4 = July-Sept)
PowerBI understands Oct-Dec to be Q4.. is there any way I can change this? 
In the photo of the date table I posted above, I tried to define the Fiscal Month and Quarter. However, these columns are not of type=date, so I cannot use them in the PREVIOUSQUARATER function. Any ideas?